# Use the_content outside the loop

Tags: loop, the-content

I was trying to get first 100 words of the content in the header, and I use the following snippet to get the first 100 words in the loop, but is it possible to get the value outside the loop:

```
$cstring = get_the_content( '' );
$newcString = substr( $cstring, 0, 100 );
echo'<p>' . $newcString . '</p>';
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are trying to do it for the current page you are on you can just use this:

```
global $post;
$content = $post->post_content;`
```

This will get the content for the current post instead of having to set the ID specifically.

Answer (score 7):

I wrote an article on [this here](http://stephenharris.info/get-post-content-by-id/), but here's a summary of the points:

- `the_content` can only be used 'inside the loop'
- 'inside the loop' can only be correctly 'simulated' by calling `setup_postdata()` and `global $post`.
- You then need to clear up after yourself by calling `wp_reset_postdata()`

The below code provides a function to retrieve post content from the post ID. It differs from [@NickYoung](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/142960/9364) answer in that the content you receive is **not** what's stored in the `post_content` column of the posts table, but rather that content **after** it's been through `the_content` filter (e.g. shortcodes parsed etc).

#### The code

```
/**
 * Display the post content. Optinally allows post ID to be passed
 * @uses the_content()
 * @link http://stephenharris.info/get-post-content-by-id/
 * @link https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/142957/use-the-content-outside-the-loop
 * @param int $id Optional. Post ID.
 * @param string $more_link_text Optional. Content for when there is more text.
 * @param bool $stripteaser Optional. Strip teaser content before the more text. Default is false.
 */
function sh_the_content_by_id( $post_id=0, $more_link_text = null, $stripteaser = false ){
    global $post;
    $post = get_post($post_id);
    setup_postdata( $post, $more_link_text, $stripteaser );
    the_content();
    wp_reset_postdata( $post );
}
```

Comment: That is a great point that it is not filtered. In that case you could use $post->post_content_filtered I think, right? I have never used that version before but it sounds like it would also do the trick.

Comment: Way to go. $post->post_content doesn't go through filters

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: `wp_reset_postdata( )` does not accept any parameter. Maybe it did, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [get_page()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page) or [get_post()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post) to get content out side the loop

```
//For page
$page_id = 1;
$get_page_object = get_page( $page_id );
$page_object = $get_page_object->post_content;
echo $newpagecString = substr($page_object, 0, 100);
//For post
$post_id = 2;
$get_post_object = get_post( $post_id );
$post_object = $get_post_object->post_content;
echo $newpostcString = substr($post_object, 0, 100);
```

Comment: And why there's `$get_page_object` when we are not calling it anywhere?

Comment: I have updated my answer.Please check now

Comment: And `$post_id = 2;` is the ID of current post? Can we call it with `$post_id = $wp_query->post->ID;` ?

Comment: $post_id is the id of that post from which you want to retrieve data.$wp_query->post->ID; will work on the loop.But i think you wanted to get content of a page or post form outside the loop.

Comment: Yea, but it's still not working in my case. Let me see what is wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0):

I found this works better: - using the get_the_content()

**Example:**

```
$content = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() );
echo $content;
```